# Retrieving the entire row containing maximum value of a field

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to calculate the Subject Area having the maximum number of books on loan. I have the following query for it:

```
SELECT SubjectArea
FROM (

  SELECT SubjectArea, MAX( Copies_On_Loan ) AS Max
  FROM (

    SELECT
      Section.SubjectArea AS SubjectArea, 
      SUM( LoanBook.Copies_On_Loan ) AS Copies_On_Loan
    FROM Section
      NATURAL JOIN Items
      NATURAL JOIN LoanBook
    GROUP BY Section.SubjectArea
  ) AS Table1
) AS Table2
```

The innermost query:

```
    SELECT 
      Section.SubjectArea AS SubjectArea, 
      SUM( LoanBook.Copies_On_Loan ) AS Copies_On_Loan
    FROM Section
      NATURAL JOIN Items
      NATURAL JOIN LoanBook
    GROUP BY Section.SubjectArea
```

returns the following table:

```
SubjectArea Copies_On_Loan
Biology         0
DBMS            3
```

**However, the entire query gives the result as Biology (instead of DBMS). Please suggest why this is happening**

Comment: Natural join?  I haven't seen one of those since the Clinton administration.

Comment: @MikeChristensen- What is an efficient alternative in the Barack Obama administration? :p

Comment: Usually, you'd explicitly specify the columns you want to `JOIN` on.  From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Natural_join): *Most experts agree that NATURAL JOINs are dangerous and therefore strongly discourage their use. The danger comes from inadvertently adding a new column, named the same as another column in the other table. An existing natural join might then "naturally" use the new column for comparisons, making comparisons/matches using different criteria (from different columns) than before.*

Comment: If I can think of a good way to do this without a temporary table or redundant derived tables, I'll post again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand what you want -- you're trying to get the Subject that has the Max(Copies_On_Loan).  If so, this should work (would be prettier if MySQL supported CTEs):

```
SELECT SubjectArea
FROM (
  SELECT MAX( Copies_On_Loan ) AS Max_Copies_On_Loan 
  FROM (
    SELECT
      Section.SubjectArea AS SubjectArea, 
      SUM( LoanBook.Copies_On_Loan ) AS Copies_On_Loan
    FROM Section
      NATURAL JOIN Items
      NATURAL JOIN LoanBook
    GROUP BY Section.SubjectArea
  ) AS Table1
) AS Table2 JOIN 
(
   SELECT
      Section.SubjectArea AS SubjectArea, 
      SUM( LoanBook.Copies_On_Loan ) AS Copies_On_Loan
    FROM Section
      NATURAL JOIN Items
      NATURAL JOIN LoanBook
    GROUP BY Section.SubjectArea
) Table3 ON Table2.Max_Copies_On_Loan  = Table3.Copies_On_Loan
```

Here is the updated [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd335/9).

Good luck.

Comment: @sgeddes- Does'nt work: gives the following result: \n
 SubjectArea \n 
 Biology  \n
        DBMS  \n

Comment: @sgeddes- It prints both rows along with their number of copies, does not select the maximum

Comment: Please see edits -- didn't realize what you wanted.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Of the top of my head, looks like you need something similar to this:

```
SELECT SubjectArea
FROM Section NATURAL JOIN Items NATURAL JOIN LoanBook
GROUP BY SubjectArea
HAVING SUM(Copies_On_Loan) = (
    SELECT MAX(M) (
        SELECT SUM(Copies_On_Loan) M
        FROM Section NATURAL JOIN Items NATURAL JOIN LoanBook
        GROUP BY SubjectArea
    ) Q1
) Q2
```

In plan English:

- Sum the loans for each subject (`SUM(Copies_On_Loan) M`) and find the maximal sum (`MAX(M)`).
- Then pick only those results where sum matches the maximum (`HAVING`).

---

*P.S.: As others have suggested, using explicit column names (in lieu of NATURAL JOIN) will make your code less "brittle".*

*P.P.S.: You should really give the database structure for questions like these, or even better a working sqlfiddle.com example so we can test the answers right away.*